# Powershell - Add rows for missing data in csv

Tags: powershell, csv

CSV file has a column with dates in order. Need to check missing dates and add empty rows for them. I am able to get what dates are missing but unable to figure out how to add rows in place of them.

```
$f=(Get-Date -Day 1)
$c=(Get-Date)
$a=@()
for($i=f;$i -lt $c;$i=$i.AddDays(1)
{
$a+=$i.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")
}

$csv=Import-Csv -Path ${FilePath} -Header "Date","Token"
$c=$csv[2..(csv.length-1)] | select "Date"
$col=@()
foreach($line in $c)
{
$properties=$line | Get-Member -MemberType Properties
for($i=0;$i -lt $properties.Count;$i++)
{
$column=$properties[$i]
$colvalue=$line | select -ExpandProperty $column.Name
$col=$col+columnvalue
}
}
$c= $a | ? {!($col -contains $_)}
```

Output- (current date 7th)

```
2023-05-01
2023-05-02
2023-05-03
2023-05-04
2023-05-05
2023-05-06
2023-05-07
```

From this I am getting the missing dates between 1st to current date. How can I add rows at the place these missing dates should be?

Csv file looks like this-

```
Name
Date       Token
2023-05-01 663
2023-05-02 522
2023-05-05 663
2023-05-07 636
```

Considering current date to be 7th missing dates would be 3,4 and 6. So I need the file to look like this-

```
Name
Date       Token
2023-05-01 663
2023-05-02 522
<row inserted>
<row inserted>
2023-05-05 663
<row inserted>
2023-05-07 636
```

Edit: All the answers are helpful for me to get an idea on how to work on this but seems like my question is not clear. I need dates till *Current day date* not last date in the csv file. So if today is June 2 I'd need all missing dates from 1st of month to current date.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following might help, added inline comments to help you with the logic.

```
$csv = @'
Date,Token
2023-05-01,663
2023-05-02,522
2023-05-05,663
2023-05-07,636
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$result = for($i = 0; $i -lt $csv.Count; $i++) {
    # $z: next Collection Index 
    # $x: next Date Index
    $z = $i + 1; $x = 0
    $current = $csv[$i]
    $date = [datetime]::Parse($current.Date, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    $current
    # while there is a next item in this collection
    while($next = $csv[$z++]) {
        # increment the next Date Index
        $x++
        # parse the date of the next collection item
        $nextDate = [datetime]::Parse($next.Date, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

        # if the date of the current item + $x is equal to the next collection item date
        if($date.AddDays($x) -eq $nextDate) {
            # break this loop
            break
        }

        # else, output a new object using the $x Date Index
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Date  = $date.AddDays($x).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
            Token = $null
        }
    }
}
```

Output would become:

```
Date       Token
----       -----
2023-05-01 663
2023-05-02 522
2023-05-03
2023-05-04
2023-05-05 663
2023-05-06
2023-05-07 636
```

Comment: This gave me the understanding on how to loop over dates but what I am looking for is not start and end with csv dates. I have my own start and end date till which I need to check the csv date column. So iterating till last csv date does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet could help:

```
$csvFileContent = @'
Date,Token
2023-05-01,663
2023-05-02,522
2023-05-05,663
2023-05-07,636
'@
$csvData = $csvFileContent | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ','
$csvDataNew = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ($csvLine in $csvData) {
    if ( $csvDataNew.Count -eq 0) {
        [void]$csvDataNew.Add( $csvLine)
    } else {
        $csvDateNext = (Get-Date -Date $csvDataNew[-1].Date
            ).AddDays(1).ToString( 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        while ($csvLine.Date -gt $csvDateNext) {
            [void]$csvDataNew.Add(
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Date  = $csvDateNext
                    Token = $null
                }
            )
            $csvDateNext = (Get-Date -Date $csvDataNew[-1].Date
                ).AddDays(1).ToString( 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        }
        [void]$csvDataNew.Add( $csvLine)
    }
}

$csvDataNew
```

**Output**: `.\SO\76375843.ps1`

```
Date       Token
----       -----
2023-05-01 663
2023-05-02 522
2023-05-03
2023-05-04
2023-05-05 663
2023-05-06
2023-05-07 636
```

Works even for unsorted input; consider

```
$csvData = $csvFileContent | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' |
    Sort-Object -Property Date
```

### Update

Used the same algorithm however input restricted to match given criteria; in the following code snippet

- partially commented code mutations, and
- slightly altered input data:

```
$csvFileContent = @'
Date,Token
2023-05-02,522
2023-06-02,222
2023-07-07,777
'@

$csvDateFirst= (Get-Date -Day 1).ToString( 'yyyy-MM-dd')
$csvDateLast = (Get-Date).ToString( 'yyyy-MM-dd')

# updated: restrict input to dates in given interval
$csvData = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(
    $csvFileContent |
        ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' |
        Where-Object {
            $_.Date -ge $csvDateFirst -and $_.Date -le $csvDateLast |
        Sort-Object -Property Date 
    })

# ensure that input contains both starting and ending dates
# BEGIN
if ($csvData.Count -eq 0 -or $csvDateFirst -lt $csvData[0].Date) {
    [void]$csvData.Insert(0, 
        [PSCustomObject]@{ Date = $csvDateFirst; Token = $null})
} elseif ($csvDateFirst -gt $csvData[-1].Date) {
    $csvData = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new(
        @([PSCustomObject]@{ Date = $csvDateFirst; Token = $null}))
}
if ($csvDateLast -gt $csvData[-1].Date) {
    [void]$csvData.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{ Date = $csvDateLast; Token = $null})
}
# END

$csvDataNew = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ($csvLine in $csvData) {
    if ( $csvDataNew.Count -eq 0) {
        [void]$csvDataNew.Add( $csvLine)
    } else {
        $csvDateNext = (Get-Date -Date $csvDataNew[-1].Date
            ).AddDays(1).ToString( 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        while ($csvLine.Date -gt $csvDateNext) {
            [void]$csvDataNew.Add(
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Date  = $csvDateNext
                    Token = $null
                }
            )
            $csvDateNext = (Get-Date -Date $csvDataNew[-1].Date
                ).AddDays(1).ToString( 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        }
        [void]$csvDataNew.Add( $csvLine)
    }
}

$csvDataNew
```

**Output**: `.\SO\76375843a.ps1`

```
Date       Token
----       -----
2023-06-01      
2023-06-02 222  
2023-06-03
```

Comment: This is neat but I need to check the csv dates from month beginning to current date so this does not work as it iterates over Date column 1st and last value.

Comment: Thanks for the unsorted one, saved my time.

Comment: @HAH answer updated; HTH…

Answer (score 0):

To compliment the helpful answers from [**Santiago Squarzon**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) and [**JosefZ**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) with a version that consumes less memory by using the [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines)

```
$Csv = @'
Date,Token
2023-05-01,663
2023-05-02,522
2023-05-05,663
2023-05-07,636
'@
```

```
# Import-Csv -Path FilePath | ...
ConvertFrom-Csv $Csv |
    Foreach-Object -Begin { $Date = [DateTime]::maxvalue } -Process {
        $_Date = Get-Date($_.Date)
        while ($Date -lt $_Date) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Date  = $Date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
                Token = $null
            }
            $Date = $Date.AddDays(1)
        }
        $_
        $Date = $_Date.AddDays(1)
    }
```

```
Date       Token
----       -----
2023-05-01 663
2023-05-02 522
2023-05-03
2023-05-04
2023-05-05 663
2023-05-06
2023-05-07 636
```